# Fijar rotación en Smartphones y Tabletas

Tags: android, android-layout

Estoy modificando una splashscreen, me interesa fijar que se visualice en vertical para smartphones y en horizontal en tabletas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar primeramente un método para detectar si el dispositivo es Tablet o télefono:

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context ctx){
                return (ctx.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}
```

por lo tanto se realizaría la validación de esta forma, mediante el uso del método **[setRequestedOrientation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int))** de tu Activity para lograr fijar la pantalla:

```
if(isTablet(getApplicationContext()){
//Es tablet, fija orientación horizontal.
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}else{
//Es teléfono, fija orientación vertical.
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

También he estado probando valores de `android:screenOrientation`dentro del `AndroidManifest.xml`y una de la posibilidades es poner `nosensor`.

- smartphones se fija en vertical `portrait`
- tabletas se fija en horizontal `landscape`
- phalbets, por determinar

Si alguien tiene una plalbet que pruebe y comente como se le visualiza si en vertical o en horizontal.